# Creating a graph for each user on my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datetime, achartengine

I'm trying to create a graph for each user that is added into my app. This graph will display the day in this format `21 Dec 2012` on the x-axis and numbers from 30 to 30000. Say this is day 1, the user adds their calorie per hour burn rate and I want that info put into the graph. The next day, I want them to be able to calculate their calorie per hour rate and store that into the graph as well. Sort of like appending it to the graph. 
    public class Graph extends Activity{

```
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
private GraphicalView mChartView;
private TimeSeries time_series;
String gotCal;
Double[] thisDou;
Double convert;

Date date;

// chart container
private LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    SharedPreferences calStuff = getSharedPreferences("Calories", 0);

    if (calStuff != null) {

        gotCal = calStuff.getString("This Cal", null);
        System.out.println(gotCal);
    }

    convert = Double.parseDouble(gotCal);

    // create dataset and renderer
    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    //mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    //mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    //mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    //mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    //mRenderer.setPointSize(3f);

    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
    //r.fillPoints(true);

    r.setFillBelowLine(true);

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Calories Burned Per Hour");
    //mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.CYAN);
    //mRenderer.setChartTitle("LOOOOOL");
    //mRenderer.setYLabels(12);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    //mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);

    time_series = new TimeSeries("test");

    mDataset.addSeries(time_series);

    fillData();

    //time_series.add(date, Double.parseDouble(gotCal));

    mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
            "dd MMM yyyy");

    if (mChartView == null)
        mChartView.repaint();

    layout.addView(mChartView);
}

private void fillData() {
    long value = new Date().getTime() - 3 * TimeChart.DAY;
    for (int i = 0; i < gotCal.length(); i += convert) {
        //date = new Date(value + i * TimeChart.DAY / 31);
        time_series.add(new Date(value + i * TimeChart.DAY / 20), i);
    }
}
```

It only works for one user, so when I try to access the graph from a different user which has different info, there's no graph, why is that? Also, how can I save the graph specifically to that user? Any help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I see this code is your graph class and I understand that you want each user to have a different graph. Is that right? Or do you want the graph to be an average graph of all users considered together?

Comment: @GauravSakhardande I want each user to have a different graph.